# How to Reset the stacks on tab change inside each tab in react native bottomTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have bottomTabNavigator in my tab and inside each tab I have stacks. I want to reset the stack whenever I click on another tab.

Tab Navigator-

Tab 1 -
|_Stack Navigator

```
         - Screen 1
               
         - Screen 2
```

Tab 2 -
|_Stack Navigator

```
         - Screen 3
               
         - Screen 4
```

Tab 3 -
|_Stack Navigator

```
         - Screen 5
         - Screen 6
```

The present scenario is,
. Suppose I am on tab 1 - I navigate to Screen 2 from screen 1
. Then I click to Tab 2
. Now if I again click on Tab 1, Screen 2 is showing instead of Screen 1.

Similar thing is happening on each  tab.

I want to reset the tab on each tab click.

Please help.

I am using -

"dependencies": {
"@react-native-community/cli": "^4.1.0",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.0.5",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.5",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.5",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
"react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.13.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
"react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
},

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@supu/nested-navigator-reset -- please check my snack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a listener on your tab screen and do your custom navigation inside

```
<AppTabs.Screen
    name="TabScreen1"
    listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
      tabPress: () => {
        navigation.navigate('Main1', { screen: 'Main2' });
      },
    })}
  />
```

Comment: I have updated my react-navigation library and it worked. Thanks Keiser.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dispatch method provided by navigation. You can dispatch a `StackActions.reset()` action on your current navigation object with an index of 0, which should hard reset the stack.